# Como funciona o tratamento de erros em tarefas assíncronas?

Tags: c#, exceção

Observando o exemplo abaixo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Test();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Nunca é capturado aqui!
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

static async void Test()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        throw new Exception("erro!");
    });
}
```

O método `Test`, contém uma tarefa assíncrona, que a mesma está atirando uma exceção, no entanto, essa exceção não é tratada quando chamo `Test` em um bloco try-catch.

> Note que estou chamando um método assíncrono a partir de um método síncrono.

Por que isso ocorre? Como fazer o bloco try-catch capturar exceções em tarefas/threads assíncronos?

Answer (score 0):

> Por que isso ocorre? Como fazer o bloco try-catch capturar exceções em
> tarefas/threads assíncronos?

Se você observar bem, há contextos diferentes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        // Aqui não há espera
        Test();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Nunca é capturado aqui!
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

static async void Test()
{
    // Enquanto que aqui, há
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        throw new Exception("erro!");
    });
}
```

Logo, se não há espera ao executar o `Test`, não tem como ele cair no `catch`, pois a execução prosseguiu e a `exception` ocorrerá após isso.

O try/catch captura as exceções sim, basta você implementar da forma correta, que é aguardando por sua tarefa.

Exemplo:

```
try
{
  await Test();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Possíveis soluções para isso:

1. Rodar tudo de forma assíncrona:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        await Test();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Nunca é capturado aqui!
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

static async Task Test()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        throw new Exception("erro!");
    });
}
```

2. Capturar o erro dentro do `Test`:

```
static async void Test()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception("erro!");
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

3. Continuar a `Task` com uma nova `Task` e lidar com o erro.

```
static async void Test()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        throw new Exception("erro!");
    }).ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine(task.Exception));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

[Resposta baseada na versão inglesa.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5383408/11263120)

Você deve colocar o try...catch dentro de sua async void ou alterar o retorno de void para **Task** e utilizar await, alterando o seu main para async.

[Como Stephen Cleary escreveu:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

> Os métodos Async void têm diferentes semânticas de tratamento de erros. Quando uma exceção é lançada de uma tarefa assíncrona ou método de tarefa assíncrona, essa exceção é capturada e colocada no objeto Task. Com métodos async void, não há nenhum objeto Task, portanto, quaisquer exceções lançadas de um método async void serão geradas diretamente no SynchronizationContext que estava ativo quando o método async void foi iniciado.

Vale lembrar que não é uma boa prática utilizar async void por algumas outras questões, como maior dificuldade de realizar testes.